# How do I echo a period every 2 seconds while 'yum -y update' is running?

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, yum

I am writing a script to do some default configuration of customers' servers, and have it nearly working 100%.

What I cannot figure out is how to run `yum -y update` in some kind of a loop that echoes a "." every two seconds while it is updating.

Here is a code example to help explain a little more

```
YUMLOG=/var/log/config.log
while [ yum -y update > $YUMLOG 2>&1 ]
do
    echo "."
    sleep 2
done
```

Obviously, that doesn't work, but I don't know what changes to make so that it *does* work. I have other parts in the code that give me this 'progress bar' effect, but nothing inside of a loop. For example:

```
if [ $SETXENNET != "y" ]; then
        sleep 1
        cp $TEMPLATEDIR/rc.local.template $TEMPLATEDIR/rc.local.new
        echo "."
        sleep 1
        cp $TEMPLATEDIR/rc.local.new /etc/rc.local
        echo "."
        sleep 1
        chmod a+x /etc/rc.local
        echo "."
        sleep 1
    else
        sleep 1
        cp $TEMPLATEDIR/rc.local.xen.template $TEMPLATEDIR/rc.local.xen.new
        echo "."
        sleep 1
        cp $TEMPLATEDIR/rc.local.xen.new /etc/rc.local
        echo "."
        sleep 1
        chmod a+x /etc/rc.local
        echo "."
        sleep 1
    fi
```

And, before I get people yelling at me for all the 'sleeps', I had to have a way to show progress of the script because the people running it will not have any idea what they are doing (they just read keystrokes from a checklist and check off when something has been done).

So, I needed a nice, clean, easy way for them to 1) see what is happening in plain English (i.e. 'done', or 'skipped') and 2) visualize that the script is still running, even if nothing is displayed on screen.

Last, I cannot make a global change to the way I am showing progress, there is too much code to have to make changes to everything it does. But, if that is the absolute only answer, I guess that may be what I have to do...some day...

Answer (score 7):

How about something like this?  The dots are printed in a function that executes in the background.  When yum is finished running, you can kill it.

```
#!/bin/bash

function dots {
   while : ; do
      echo -n ". "
      sleep 2s
   done
}

dots &
pid=$!

# do real work here
sleep 15s

kill -9 $pid
echo "done!"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. Have `yum` work in the background, and first create a temporary file, then delete it afterwards. The main process just loops, sleeps and prints while the file exists:

```
(touch tmpfile ; yum ... ; rm tmpfile)&
(while test -e tmpfile ; do echo . ; sleep 2 ; done)
```